# is popen really thread safe?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, popen

Recently, I am running into trouble of calling popen, it seems to be not thread safe.

The following is the code snippet from the source code link: http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/bionic/libc/upstream-netbsd/lib/libc/gen/popen.c

```
static struct pid {
   struct pid *next;
   FILE *fp;
   int fd;
   pid_t pid;
} *pidlist;

static rwlock_t pidlist_lock = RWLOCK_INITIALIZER;

FILE *
popen(const char *command, const char *type)
{
   struct pid *cur, *old;
   ...
   pipe2(pdes, flags)                 // A
   ...
   (void)rwlock_rdlock(&pidlist_lock);     // C
   ...
   switch (pid = vfork()) {                // C.1
     case 0:             /* Child. */
        ...
        _exit(127);
        /* NOTREACHED */
    }

    /* Parent; */
   ...
   /* Link into list of file descriptors. */
   cur->fp = iop;
   cur->pid =  pid;
   cur->next = pidlist;          // D
   pidlist = cur;                // E

   (void)rwlock_unlock(&pidlist_lock); // F
   ...
}
```

Observing the above code, it acquired a read-lock at C, but, inside the scope, it did some write operations at E.  So, there will be possibly multiple read threads who are writing to the variable "pidlist" in the same time.

Does anyone know whether it is a true issue or not?

Comment: What's the next line after `vfork()`?  If it isn't a call to one of the `exec...()` functions, that would be a Bad Thing.  In general, forking a Linux process after it has created one or more new threads also is a bad thing, but I don't know how that rule applies when you're talking about `vfork()`/`exec()`.

Comment: At a quick glance, I agree. I don't see what would prevent two different `struct pid` nodes being initialized and racing to set the new `pidlist` value. That would result in one of the two nodes getting left out of the list. Looks to me like it should be a write-lock.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, it is not how you outline it.

Here is a paste from the given link http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/bionic/libc/upstream-netbsd/lib/libc/gen/popen.c

```
80FILE *
81popen(const char *command, const char *type)
82{
83  struct pid *cur, *old;
94  if (strchr(xtype, '+')) {
...
100 } else  {
103     if (pipe2(pdes, flags) == -1)
104         return NULL;
105 }
106
...
113
114 (void)rwlock_rdlock(&pidlist_lock);
115 (void)__readlockenv();
116 switch (pid = vfork()) {
117 case -1:            /* Error. */
...
127 case 0:             /* Child. */
...
154     execl(_PATH_BSHELL, "sh", "-c", command, NULL);
155     _exit(127);
156     /* NOTREACHED */
157 }
158 (void)__unlockenv();
159
160 /* Parent; assume fdopen can't fail. */
161 if (*xtype == 'r') {
...
167 } else {
...
173 }
...
179 pidlist = cur;
180 (void)rwlock_unlock(&pidlist_lock);
181
182 return (iop);
183}
```

It is

```
do the file stuff (pipe2() or socketpair())
acquire the lock (this will avoid the child doing silly things)
vfork()
on the child, reorganize filedes and execl
on parent do some filedes stuff unlock and return
```

I do not see what would be the problem.

Comment: I think you missed the point. The issue is in the parent only -- having to do with the `pidlist` being manipulated without a write lock (at the same time in different threads).